# Password encryption in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web

I used a mysql database to create a user's registration form and in my sign up code, I did not specify the encryption type for password. How do I create a login form in php which requires password?

Comment: You really must attempt this by searching other SO answers or other sites on how to accomplish your issue. The community will not do your work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.